# SUM after GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite

Here is mytable

```
   customerID  invoice     payment
   1            101            300
   1            101            300
   3            102            200
   4            103            200
   1            104            200
```

What I want to do is, first: group invoice, then sum the payment of grouped invoice (300+200)

```
 select customerID  , sum(payment) as totalpaid from mytable WHERE
 customerID  ='1' group by `invoice`
```

Expected result is 500. But I'm getting 800 using above code. How to do that correctly?

Comment: Why are you expecting 300?

Comment: You should get 600, because you have two consumer IDs of 1, at 300 each.

Comment: Jordan S, Gyhth : I've some messed up table where this kind of duplicated data is available. Now how to get the job done? How to filter those entry and get one value 300 ?

Comment: @Zils How do you decide what is legitimate data and what is duplicated?

Comment: As in: do you want to remove exact duplicates (and based on what column set), or something else?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli @ Sami Kuhmonen : First: I wan to group same `invoice` as single entry, then I want to sum total value `payment` which was previously grouped. How should i proceed to do that?

Comment: I've updated the question & add some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude duplicates use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT 
  customerID, 
  SUM(payment) as totalpaid 
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT customerID, invoice, payment FROM customers) 
GROUP BY customerID
```

For `customerID = 1` you can do

```
SELECT 
  customerID, 
  SUM(payment) as totalpaid 
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT customerID, invoice, payment FROM customers) 
WHERE customerID = 1
```

no need to `GROUP BY`.